# How to recover a file damaged by ntfs resizing?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery, ntfs

I resized an ntfs partition to free space for another partition. It had just a few files, the most important being 2 big Bzip2 files.

I resized using gparted and it gave me no errors, everything was successful.

However, the filesystem presented problems. I used chkdsk to fix it, and after recovering, the two files got corrupted, they now seem have 0 bytes, and the information on MFT is missing (like the sector count and sector offset). All other files are ok.

Bzip2 files are specially tricky to recover by scanning a drive's surface. The end-of-stream flag is bit-aligned, not byte-aligned, but I did make a script to identify the flag, but it would only work if they're not fragmented.

Do you have any idea of how can I recover those files?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than make your own script, does [TestDisk](cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)'s undelete functionality save you?  (Recommended: first make a forensic image.   Although it is a bit late for that, as you've run Chkdsk.  Still might be good to prevent further steps from harming your options.)

Comment: You have that level of knowledge but did not know enough to back the files up first? Have you tried photorec ?

Comment: There was a back up I made about 3 months ago, on  my father's laptop, but he dropped it on the floor and damaged the hard drive. 

That`s why I didn't care do backup first, but then I found out about that, so now I need to recover it from my drive.

I didn't try photorec/testdisk for now, I don't have any other drive to copy things to yet. I want to be sure of what to do before. My script wasn't made to copy it, it was only to analyze the hard drive so I could have an idea of how things are before I proceed.

Answer (score 1):

> I used `chkdsk` to fix it, and after recovering, the two files got corrupted, they now seem have 0 bytes, and the information on MFT is missing (like the sector count and sector offset). [...] but it would only work if they're not fragmented.
>
> Do you have any idea of how can I recover those files?

You can't. As you said, you used `chkdsk` to "fix" the MFT and that command pruned the `$DATA` attribute of the file record (aka MFT entry).

There are basically two options when it comes to data recovery:

- following the file system (what Testdisk does) → ruled out because you destroyed the `$DATA` attribute so there is no information about the fragments
- using a carving tool (like Photorec) → this works only for non-fragmented files, as you pointed out before

For this reason, you cannot recover the files if they were fragmented. Unless, of course, you are able to *manually* identify them one by one and you manage to combine them in the correct order. That sounds quite difficult.